# Exclude a file in /var/www/html from SSL in apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, server

I have a home server running on apache at `/var/www/html`, I also created a self signed SSL at `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`

How can I exclude a file within `html` from SSL, for example, my current server is `https://myserver.com`, but I want to use `http://myserver.com/nossl/api.php`

What should I add in .htaccess of that `nossl` folder?

This is my current .htaccess to exclude authentication

```
<Files main.php>
    AuthType none
    Satisfy any

    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't find any direct solution to this, I did find a way of free SSL using [letsencrypt](https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt)

Working great on multiple servers